# Save printing preference of excel 2003

Tags: excel, printing

I am using excel 97-2003 (its a 2007 excel saved in compatibility mode) to take print on a cheque.The print area and the paper size(Envelope Monarch) is preset,meaning when I press ctrl+P the page size is by default selected as Envelope Monarch and the pre-selected print area appears.The problem I face here is : in print preview it shows two pages-first one is my required page and second page is blank.I need to everytime select 'page 1 of 1' to avoid blank print page.Is there any way so that on ctrl+P it will always print only first page by default.I am fine with adding macros as well please help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Page Layout tab and set width and height to 1 page